# Anti-aliasing not working in Normal bake

Tags: normals, texture-baking, antialiasing

**The Scene**

So in the scene i have a high poly model and a flat plane to which i want to bake the normals on to. The engine i am using here is ***Blender Render***
[image]

**The Models**

Just a flat plane (*to which i want to bake the normals on*) and the high poly sculpted mesh
[image]

**The *texture* settings of the flat plane**

Regular normal map settings here, checked the normal in the *Influence* and checked the normal map option in the *Image sampling panel*

[image]

**The Anti-aliasing and Bake settings**

Regular normal bake settings with the anti-aliasing turned on.

[image]

**The Question**

As you can see the normal map still has jagged edges despite anti-aliasing being enabled. I baked it multiple times to see if it worked, but still got nothing. They still bake out with jagged lines. I am at the ends of my wit here. How do i fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TexTools for Blender was recently released (free) which adds an anti-aliasing option for baking.

[image: Anti alias option]

Internally the add-on just renders at 2x or 4x the size and then down-scales the final bake to the target resolution resulting in anti aliasing. The good thing is that this anti-aliasing works with all bake modes in TexTools.

You can find more information and download links from [my website](http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/).

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Please not that you must explicitly state it's your own website you're linking to: read [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to anti-alias normal baking in blender internal with the standard feature-set. 
The fastest workaround is to quadruple your texture bake size and then resize/resample it with an image editing program to the desired size.

Alternatively you could try the yPanel addon
https://youtu.be/ghJgnjskwyM?t=379
Download: https://github.com/ucupumar/yPanel

Be advised this is a relatively fresh addon and i have no idea how well it works.

Comment: I have tried it, the jagged edges are still there. The problem is that the anti-aliasing works (without the addon) when I try to bake some other object. There seems to be something wrong with plane or the sculpt mesh but I can't figure it out.